# Lasso as feature selection on its own, e.g. before random forest classification

Tags: classification, feature-selection, random-forest, lasso

Could lasso be used by itself as a feature selection method without being tied to a regression loss function? And if so, what's a good package for doing so?

Also, could lasso be performed as a step before using a classifier like random forest?

Comment: Lasso is a regression method. It's not a meaningful concept to talk about uncoupling it from a regression loss function. In some situations, you can apply an l1 penalty (as lasso uses) to the weights of other methods (e.g. logistic regression). This can induce sparse weights, mimicking the feature selection effect that lasso has. You could also take the features selected by lasso regression and use them for something else. This might or might not make sense, depending on the situation.

Comment: Doing this for random forests wouldn't make much sense because lasso is a linear regression method. If the true relationship is linear, there's no use for a nonlinear method like RFs. If the true relationship is nonlinear, then lasso wouldn't be of much help.